# How do I prove the existence of x that satisfies this inequality?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I'm trying to solve this inequality:

$(a+b+c+ab+ac+bc+abc)/7 > x > abc > 1$, where $a,b,c > 0$ and real-numbered, with the caveat:
 x is supposed to be a member of this set {${a,b,c,ab,ac,bc}$}. I'd like to know whether such $x$ exists or not. If you can't find out, I want to know that too, and the reason for that as well.

I know that there exist an $x$ such that $(a+b+c+ab+ac+bc+abc)/7 > x > abc > 0$, by trial and error.

Here's the full story on how this problem came to be. I wonder if it would help...

Let's say you invested in a stock. Its return over the first period is $a$, return over the second period $b$, third period $c$, and so on. Now, if you buy at the first period and keep holding until the third period, your return on this stock is $abc$. Thus, $(a+b+c+ab+ac+bc+abc)/7 > abc$ means that among all possible trading sequences, buying and holding until the end ($abc$) was not really a good choice, because you did worse than the mean of all possible trading sequences $(a+b+c+ab+ac+bc+abc)/7$.

Then the inequality above is asking this:
Can you earn a positive return without trading(buy-and-hold), but do worse than the others who trade, given that you have to hold this asset over 3(possibly extend to n) periods?

Since it involves proving/solving here is the right place... right? If not please forgive me ;)

Comment: Is $x$ allowed to change for different values of $a, b, c$? IE do you mean $ x = \min(a, b, c, ab, ac, bc)$? Also, note that $ac$ can only be achieved as a return if you allow for repeated buy and hold.

Answer (score 0):

If $a=b=c=1$, then

$$\frac{ a+b+c+ab+bc+ca+abc}{7} = 1 = abc.$$

Hence no such $x$ exists (strict inequality).